# rosbuild overlay of prosilica camera in Hydro

Tags: catkin, rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I need to use a modified version of the prosilica camera driver in Ros Hydro. I have followed the tutorials and I have set up an overlaying catkin workspace with rosbuild. Everything seems fine, but when I try to build the package, all I get is a lot of messages saying the packages are marked with a ROS_NOBUILD flag and I cannot wonder why.

The output of rosmake is:

```
    [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['prosilica_camera']                                                              
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['prosilica_camera']                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/marbosjo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131025-104949                                   
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['prosilica_camera'] to:
['prosilica_camera']                                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg                                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> prosilica_gige_sdk [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                                                                       
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph                            
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
 No Makefile in package console_bridge          
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< prosilica_gige_sdk ROS_NOBUILD in package prosilica_gige_sdk
 No Makefile in package prosilica_gige_sdk
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean                            
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp                               
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp                                  
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy                                     
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime                               
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam rosmaster: 0.0 sec ] [ roslan... [ 8 Active 11/48 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package rosparam                            
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
 No Makefile in package class_loader                
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits             
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
 No Makefile in package pluginlib                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs             
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                       
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs             
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs       
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp                                  
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy                                     
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                   
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout                                  
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
 No Makefile in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_updater
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters       
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
 No Makefile in package topic_tools                   
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test
 No Makefile in package self_test                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
 No Makefile in package image_transport       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera
 No Makefile in package polled_camera             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base
 No Makefile in package driver_base                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> prosilica_camera [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< prosilica_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package prosilica_camera                                             
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Built 48 packages with 0 failures.                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] /home/marbosjo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131025-104949
```

Finally I have managed to build the package with make and adding a Makefile with the following line:

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

But I cannot install it, or use it from the location of the workspace, so I have to manually copy the files in the ROS_ROOT.

Any idea about how to build it with rosmake?
Any idea about how to install o use the package compiled with make, without manually moving the files to ROS_ROOT?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94216/rosbuild-overlay-of-prosilica-camera-in-hydro./) by [marbosjo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8116/marbosjo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake only builds rosbuild packages, not catkin packages. You should not invoke rosmake in folders with catkin packages, as that will only give you the ROS_NOBUILD messages.

And rosbuild packages cannot easily be installed, that's one of the reasons for the switch to catkin. Rosbuild packages are more intended to be used without being installed.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marbosjo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8116/marbosjo/) on 2013-10-25**:
So what is the best way to overlay a rosbuild package in hydro?

I followed this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) but I get stucked in the errors I have mentioned.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-25**:
The tutorial explain everything. Put rosbuild_ws next to catkin_ws, not one inside the other. Run rosmake only within rosbuild_ws. Do not install rosbuild packages, just use rosbuild_ws/setup.sh to run overlayed code. Do not move files to ROS_ROOT.

**Comment by [marbosjo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8116/marbosjo/) on 2013-10-25**:
Finally I have managed to build the package by switching to the branch "master" of the git repository.

Thank you!